# Is there any name for the vector space does not suppose zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I know the definition of the vector space includes the existence of the zero vector. Is there any theory on the space satisfying all the definitions of the vector space but the existence of the zero vector? Thank you.

Comment: No, you will immediately lose the additive inverses.

Comment: Also you would lose much of multiplication by scalars. So it would not be a useful structure. But the short answer is that there is no accepted name for such a structure.

Comment: One could argue that affine space is such a thing; it's a vector space with no origin, but we don't really have a vector space structure anymore, just a notion of affine subspaces.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks! This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) is essentially a vector space where we forget about the origin. Addition is no longer completely possible, but there is an associated vector space that acts on the affine space by translation, and we can still take linear combinations if the sum of the coefficients is $1$.